# gdcl multiplexer create file with raw video not h264

Tags: directshow, h.264, mpeg-4

i have created one graph as per below (i am using osprey card for input live stream)

(graphedit tool)

Osprey analog video in ----> GDCL MPEG-4 mulitplexer ----> File Writer (.mp4 file)

filesize is very big; even 5 seconds file have 80 mb size.
file doesn't get played.

when i see file detail in ffmpeg with ffmpeg -i,

it will give error like stream 0, missing mandatory atoms, broken header

below is ffmpeg response.

> ffmpeg.exe -i "C:\Documents and Setti
>   ngs\Administrator\Desktop\mp4file\mp4file.mp4"
>   ffmpeg version N-38938-ge01f478 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
>     built on Mar 19 2012 23:18:25 with gcc 4.6.2
>     configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3
>    --disable-w32threads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzli
>   b --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable
>   -libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
>   ibrtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-li
>   bvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-l
>   ibx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
>     libavutil      51. 42.100 / 51. 42.100
>     libavcodec     54. 12.100 / 54. 12.100
>     libavformat    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
>     libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
>     libavfilter     2. 65.101 /  2. 65.101
>     libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
>     libswresample   0.  7.100 /  0.  7.100
>     libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
>   [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 003E28E0] stream 0, missing mandatory atoms, broken h
>   eader
>   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator
>   \Desktop\mp4file\mp4file.mp4':
>     Metadata:
>       major_brand     : mp42
>       minor_version   : 0
>       compatible_brands: mp42isom
>     Duration: 00:00:00.00, bitrate: -2147483 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(eng): Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 90k
>    tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
>       Metadata:
>         handler_name    :
>   At least one output file must be specified

do i need to make any gdcl filter settings?
please help me to solve problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multiplexer is used to multiplex different streams into a single file. Most of the time this will be an audio and a video stream. But a multiplexer does not encode audio or video. If you need h.264 video, you need to add a h264 encoder to the graph. For example you can use [ffdshow](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) for that.

See also wikipedia for the [mp4 file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14), [H.264 video compression format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding), and [other parts of mpeg4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4#MPEG-4_parts).

If you really mean to create an uncompressed .mp4 file, take a look at the [official supported formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14#Data_streams) for .mp4. Uncompressed video is probably not officially supported. But even if it is, you also need support from both the multiplexer as the player. On his website Geraint Davies has added the following [note](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/):

> Note: both mux and demux filters need a small amount of code added for
>   each media type that is to be supported. So far I have only added a
>   limited set of types. If you need other types to be accepted, please
>   get in touch directly It's likely that only a few lines of code will
>   be needed.

It is probably better to use [MXF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Exchange_Format) for uncompressed video.

Comment: Thanks wimmel, i want to use h.264 encoder; so as per your suggestion i have downloaded ffdshow and use few ways (in graphedt.exe) but doesn't work properly, can you help me to use (build graph) it please (actually i am new to video capture process).

Comment: also i can only able to see below options as encoder
uncompressed,
mjpeg,
huffyuv,
ffvi
dv

Comment: Please ask a separate question. And explain a bit more in detail what the problem is, and what you have tried to solve it.